# How do I get the latest version of Microsoft.SharePoint.Client in my project?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have a project that accesses SharePoint and downloads files from it. The 
version of `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime` in the project is `14.0.0.0` and I want to update it because lately the project has not been working and I believe it is because of the version of these assemblies.

Do I need to install `Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM` `16.1.6518.1200` or can I 
install `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime` 
separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the SharePoint Client SDK from the [MSDN downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038). To upgrade your solution by following below steps.

1. Open your solution from Visual Studio.
2. Go to your solution references.

[image]

3. Open library references by right click on dll (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client)  reference.

[image]

4. Change the path property to where the dll is located. my solution reference is as follows.

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll`

Answer (score 3):

You can get the latest by downloading the nuget package. In visual studio, go to tools->nuget package manager->manage nuget packages for this solution. Click on the browse tab and search SharePoint Online. Follow the prompts to install the nuget package.